# Infinite Message boxes

Tags: c

I need a little help on this one. The code seems fine. But when I run and I input a non-numeric number, it shows the messagebox error infinitely and won't stop unless I kill the program. Can someone show me a way to fix it? Thanks!

CODE:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #define pi 3.1416

    int main()
    {
        float rad, area, dia, circ;
        int radint;
        char resp;
        start:
        system("cls");
        printf("Chapter 1 \t\t\tProblem 1\n\n");
        printf("Input the circle's radius: ");
        radint = scanf("%f", &rad);
        if(rad < 0)
        {
            MessageBox(0, "There cannot be negative measurements.", "Negative Value", 0);
goto start;
        }
        if(radint < 1)
        {
            MessageBox(0, "Non-numeric value is inputted.", "Character Value", 0);
            goto start;
        }
        dia = rad * 2;
        circ = 2 * pi * rad;
        area = pi * rad * rad;
        printf("\n\nDiameter = %0.2f | Circumference = %0.2f | Area = %0.2f\n\n", dia, circ, area);
        printf("Try again? [Y/N]: ");
        ret:
        resp = getchar();
        switch(resp)
        {
            case 'y': goto start;
            case 'n': return;
            default: goto ret;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: Please don't `#define pi 3.1416`. Even Visual Studio should have `<math.h>`, which defines `M_PI`.

Comment: "isalpha() C Function faulty?" - **No.**

Comment: Find a way to make this program without using `goto`, `system(cls)` and os-specific things like `MessageBox` and your program will probably become 10-100 times better. You might be able to fix your problem as well in the course of this exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `isalpha` on a `float`. `isalpha` expects a small integer.

From the standard:

> The header  declares several functions useful for classifying
>   and mapping characters.198) **In all cases the argument is an int, the
>   value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char** or shall
>   equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value,
>   the behavior is undeﬁned.

There are contrived ways to make `isalpha` work on a `float` but it's probably not what you want.

You don't need to use `isalpha` at all. As Stefano Sanfilippo suggested in another answer you just have to check the value returned by `scanf`: **the number of successful matches**.

In other words if you ask for a float and `scanf` returns 1, then by all means the user must have typed something that must look like a `float` and you can just use that.

Comment: I just did that, and it's fixed. But there is still one problem: if I input an error value (anything that's not a number), the dialog box won't stop appearing. It infinitely loops.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha` expects an `int` as input (actually interpreted as `unsigned char` or `EOF`), not a floating point number. The number you pass as parameter is casted to `int` and it falls outside the alphanumeric range.

You can check if the number was correctly parsed by testing the return value of `scanf`:

```
int converted = scanf("%f", &rad);

if (converted < 1) {
    MessageBox(0, "Non-numeric value is inputted.", "Character Value", 0);
}
```

and removing the `isalpha` branch.

Comment: Please define "it won't work". Are the output values wrong? Or what?

Comment: It works now IF I input a numeric value. But if I input a non-numeric value, the dialog box' appearance loops infinitely.

Comment: I guess you should rework that `goto`. Try adding `goto start;` after `MessageBox` in the `if` above. Better, get rid of those `goto`.